# How to change the background color and the font color

Tags: html, css

[I want to add background color to black and I even want to change the text color to white, P.S I am new to coding please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kGS6.png)

Comment: Well, you have the color  property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) and the background/background-color properties (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)

Comment: You don't have a selector specified. Of what element are you trying to change the text color?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `color` and `background-color`

**EDIT**
You also need to select the elements you want to apply your style, You can check the different [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)  and the possibilities.

In the example below, I made a class "text" applyed to a div. Every elements having the class "text" will have a white color and a black background.

```css
.text{
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Hello
</div>
<div>
  Hello (not affected)
</div>
<div class="text">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: he uses the color property. He just never specified a selector and as such those CSS decleration didnt take any effect. It is a typo caused issue that shouldnt have been answered.

Comment: @tacoshy I didn't pay attention to this fact. He still needs to use `background-color`. I updated my answer to speak about selectors.